# Django add prefix to AutoField

Tags: python, django, autofield

Is there a way to create an `AutoField` in Django that always begins with a certain prefix?

I would like to create an `AutoField` that always begin with the number 1, where the first 15 saved records would have the values `11, 12, 13, 14, ..., 19, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can't create a second `AutoField` if one is already being used for the primary key because some database backends (such as MySQL) does not support it. See https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/8576

Second, no, you can't do that but you *can* override `save` method to populate a second column that will concatenate `1` with your automatically generated `id`, i.e.:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    custom_id = models.IntegerField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.custom_id is None:
            self.custom_id = int('1' + str(self.id))
        return super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks!  It was never my intention to create a second `AutoField`, since that doesn't make sense.  But thanks for the save override idea!